# Access data attribute value via variable

Tags: jquery, html, attributes

Below, you can find a screenshot from the "selected"-Object, i am using. It is a select-list. I receive the object with following code (using jQuery):

```
var addArticle = $('.add-article'); // div.add-article
// selector is a dynamic value, that defines, which select-list should be "found"
var select = addArticle.find('[data-id=' + selector + ']');
```

The object-selection works fine. But when i want to get the data-attribute values (values are numbers), i fail to get them.

[image: Object image here]

i tried many variations to get the values, but here is an example of it

```
//$this.selectors is an array with all values beween data- and -id
$.each($this.selectors, function (i, el) {
    //return if last needed data attribute was read
    if (i == $this.lastAsInt) {
        return false;
    }
    // "generate" data-selector
    selector = '[data-' + el + '-id]';

    // select = object from the image (see link), also tried with data()
    location[el] = select.find(':selected').find(selector);
});
```

I hope, someone could understand my problem :)

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking, but if you're trying to select the element from the `data` attribute you build in `selector`, then you need to wrap it in `[]` like this: `selector = '[data-' + el + '-id]';`. If that isn't what you need, the please edit your question to make it what you're trying to do much clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a variable where you store your "selected" object for example `var myObject`

Then you can simply get the data attribute with **jQuery's** `.data()` :

```
myObject.data('room-id');
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLztmkt0/1/)

Comment: in my case this does not work. And i have to access the data attribute via myObject.data(variable).

Comment: I am so sorry. My problem was, that the object could not be read inside the function (bc accessibility...)